# Getting a gun to fire

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm trying to make a top down shooter game to learn about coding in HTML/JS/CSS.

I've got a canvas, my player moves and rotates on the canvas, but I'm having some trouble getting his gun working.  I've got this with the aid of tutorials and searching through other stackoverflow posts, but this one I can't seem to fix alone.

I have defined a variable 'gunfire' which is set to 1 if the left mouse button is pressed and is otherwise 0, in my function draw() I have an if statement that should draw a rectangle in front of my sprite (to represent bullets) when the left mouse button is pressed.

The problem I have is that the bullets appear at all times, independent of whether the mouse button is pressed.  If anyone can point out what it is that I'm doing wrong then I would be very grateful, here's the code (the canvass is created in separate HTML/CSS files):

```
var turn = 0;
var frameRate = 24;
var main_x = 0,
    main_y = 0,
    move_x = 0,
    move_y = 0;
var gunfire = 0;
var speed = 4;

function keyPress(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 68) { //d
        move_x = speed;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 65) { //a
        move_x = -speed;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 83) { //s
        move_y = speed;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 87) { //w
        move_y = -speed;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 1) { //left mouse
        gunfire = 1;
    }
}

function keyRelease(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 68) { //d
        move_x = 0;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 65) { //a
        move_x = 0;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 83) { //s
        move_y = 0;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 87) { //w
        move_y = 0;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 1) { //left mouse
        gunfire = 0;
    }    
}

function move() {
    main_x += move_x;
    main_y += move_y;

    if (main_x < -220) {
        main_x = -220
    }
    if (main_y < -220) {
        main_y = -220
    }
    if (main_x > 220) {
        main_x = 220
    }
    if (main_y > 220) {
        main_y = 220
    }    
}

function mouseMove(e) {
    var mouseX, mouseY;
    if (e.offsetX) {
        mouseX = e.offsetX;
        mouseY = e.offsetY;
    } else if (e.layerX) {
        mouseX = e.layerX;
        mouseY = e.layerY;
    }
    mouseX = mouseX - (top_canvas.width / 2) - main_x;
    mouseY = mouseY - (top_canvas.height / 2) - main_y;
    window.radians = Math.atan2(mouseY, mouseX);
    //document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = radians
}

var background = new Image();
background.src = "assets/background3.jpg";
var player1 = new Image();
player1.src = "assets/player1.png";

function draw() { //draws all content on the canvas
    ctx_1.save();
    ctx_1.clearRect(0, 0, top_canvas.width, top_canvas.height);
    ctx_1.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
    ctx_1.translate(top_canvas.width / 2 + main_x, top_canvas.height / 2 + main_y);
    ctx_1.rotate(turn);
    ctx_1.drawImage(player1, -25, -25, 50, 70);

    if (gunfire = 1) {
        ctx_1.fillStyle = "#000";
        ctx_1.fillRect(0, -10, 200, 20);
    }
    ctx_1.restore();
}

function gameLoop() {
    // all functions to update go here
    draw();
    turn = window.radians
    move();
}

function init() {
    window.top_canvas = document.getElementById("top_canvas");
    window.ctx_1 = top_canvas.getContext("2d");
    setInterval(gameLoop, 1000 / frameRate);
    //event fires every time the mouse moves
    top_canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove, false);
    window.addEventListener("keydown", keyPress, false);
    window.addEventListener("keyup", keyRelease, false);
}

window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as Kippie points out, you're setting `gunfire` to 1 each time which results in a true statement. It must be changed to `==` `or ===` (latter preferable) or simply drop the comparison as the non-zero value would be true:

```
if (gunfire) {
   ...
}
```

Second, you are checking for mouse clicks inside a *key handler* and assuming `keyCode` would indicate a mouse button click. `keyCode` 1 is not related to mouse clicks at all and no mouse clicks will end up here.

Third, you are not having any event handler for mouse clicks...

To solve these issues (in addition to the first) add an event handler for mouse clicks:

```
top_canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown, false);
window.addEventListener("mouseup",   mouseUp,   false);
```

Then inside the handlers (only showing for mouse down):

```
function mouseDown(e) {

    if (e.button === 0) { // check left mouse-button
        gunfire = 1;
    }
}
```

The reason for using window for mouse up is that in case your mouse pointer is outside the canvas element the up event won't register and the gun will continue to fire. Using the window object will allow you to register up event even in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

`if (gunfire = 1)`

You're using the assignment operator, rather than doing a comparison.
Use === instead.

Comment: Kippie - that stops the gun from firing permanently but now it doesn't fire when the mouse button is pressed.